# Show cairo graphics in windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, svg, cairo

I generate some graphics using luacairo and would like to show them in a .dot net c# program (windows forms not WPF). I generate some scientific graphs. Cairo can generate a variety of graphics formats and I am not sure which is the best choice for this task. SVG seems the best choice in principle but it seems to be very complicated to draw SVGs in winforms. I only want to display the graphics and allow the user to zoom in and out but not change the graphics itself. Can you suggest the optimal graphics format for this task?

P.S.: I found https://github.com/vvvv/SVG for drawing SVGs but it seems to be quite complex. If you think that is still the best solution: Is there a simple example making use of this library?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166456%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) out. Microsoft example on using SVG graphics.
Essentially going for SVG is the best because it's a vector drawing so there is virtually no visual losses.

If you can output CAD or obj then you can use AutoCad Library otherwise there is other less known CAD control makers. Here i use [VectorDraw](http://www.vdraw.com/). Pretty much like solidworks/autocad and it does both 2D and 3D vector.

Comment: Thanks, the microsoft SVG sample sounds good. It's just that I do not see how I can download the samples or the SDK. In the 2013 SDK there does not seem to be an SVG example and for the 2005 SDK I only found broken links. Or did I miss something? Are the samples still available somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have VS 2005. I downloaded an .iso file containing it but it won't install on Windows 8.1 (which is probably understandable). Unfortunately it is also not possible to find the examples folder on the CD I burned - I guess the samples are contained in a compressed files which is unpacked by the installation routine - which does not work on WIn 8.1. I will try to find somebody who still has a copy of VS2005 and can send me the example.

Comment: I struggle with the same issue, did you find a solution? Typical Microsoft to leave this open end!

Comment: once parsed you can always draw using Viewport3D ad #Dpoint in WPF. [Fluid kit](http://fluidkit.codeplex.com/) have a good simple 3D implementation. Also SharpGL is offering good solutions